# ubuntu 14.04 Apache 2.4.7 mpm_event Files and FilesMatch not working

Tags: apache-2.4, php-fpm, cache, regex, mpm-prefork

We recently switched our Apache 2.4.7 mode from mpm_pre-fork to mpm_event.
Since then we haven't been able to get our `Files` directive to work.

```
<Files "*.php">
  Header set Cache-Control "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, max-age=0"
</Files>
```

I did manage to get working with this convoluted mess:

```
<Files ~ "((^$)|(php))">
```

But, according to my regex knowledge, this will match files with "php" anywhere in the file name.
I found the need to match the "null" case from [this other question](https://serverfault.com/questions/648262/filesmatch-configuration-to-restrict-file-extensions-served).
We've also tried `FilesMatch` with the same result.

None of this makes any sense from what I can tell from the Apache 2.4 documentation.  Has anyone else seen anything like this problem?

**UPDATE**:
I rolled the server back to mpm_preforker and mod_php with no change.  I then purged apache and php, re-installed as mpm_preforker and it worked again.  I then upgraded to mpm_event and php-fpm and it stopped working after a bit.  I'm trying to isolate where it breaks and will post what I find.

**UPDATE2**:
This appears to be related to the fastcgi or php-fpm stuff.
I have two `<Files>` directives, one for `html` and one for `php` that generate unique headers:

```
<Files *.html>
   Header always set X-Aaron-files "html match"
</Files>
<Files *.php>
   Header always set X-Aaron-files "php match"
</Files>
```

If I go to a fictitious `php` file, then I get a 404 message with the header for `php-match`.
BUT if I go to a real `php` file, then the server executes the php file but does NOT return the headers indicating a `php` file match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be related to the fastcgi and php-fpm stuff.
Not sure how this made it through testing....

If the requested file **is** handled by php-fpm, then the directives **are not** processed.

If instead the file **is not** handled by php-fpm (which includes 404 responses for a missing php file), then the directives **are** processed.

Answer (score 1):

`<Files "*.php">` works

Try another thing than a header, like a redirect page :

```
<Files "*.php">
redirect 301 / /anyPage.htm
</Files>
```

If you want to do the same with regexp you can do

```
<Files ~ "\.php">
redirect 301 / /anyPage.htm
</Files>
```

If you want to make the match to nothing & any php page:

```
<Files ~ "(^$|\.php)">
redirect 301 / /anyPage.htm
</Files>
```

Using filematch :

```
<FilesMatch "(^$|\.php)">
    redirect 301 / /anyPage.htm
</FilesMatch>
```

You can make the test it will works.

I suspect you got some intruction somewhere else which override your header

Comment: Like I said, all we did was switch from mpm_prefork to mpm_event with php-fpm. How can we find if some instruction that overrides the items in the virtualHost tag?  Most of our testing was to create custom headers, just to see if the directives were being processed correctly, that's how we found a pattern that finally worked.

Comment: See updates in OP.